# Odoo 8 How to allow access to the documents of Document Management Module if you are not an employee

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have installed the Document Management Module. I have some users who represent companies, and they only belong to the knowledge group so they can view some documents. If I try this configuration, these users can view the directories, but they can´t view the documents inside them. Instead of that, they get an error saying that they must be employees to view the content of the directories. I do not want them to belong to the human resources / employee group. I just want them to belong to the knowledge group. I Hope you can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an access role for this. 
Enable the developer mode and then - 
Go to Settings > Users > Groups.

Select the group to which you want to give the access.

Go to the Access Rights Tab and then add an item into it.

Select 
- object - 'ir.attachment'
- Read, Write, Create, Unlink (Check all or as per your requirement) and - - give a name to the rule (any name).

And save it.

The user belonging to that particular group will have access to the document management module.

Thanks
Shikhar S

Comment: I already had contemplated the access to ir.attachment object for the knowledge users. If I add those users to the group Human resources/ Employees, they can automatically see the contents of the directories. I think my problem is some permission that Human resources/ Employee has, but the Knowledge/user group does not have. In the group Human resources/ Employee there are more than 70 different permissions, and I don't know which may be the missing knowledge group.

Answer (score 0):

The model `ir.attachment` in Odoo has some special logic for access rights. An user doesn't only need access rights to that model, but additionally need access rights to the model to which the attachments belongs.

An easy example: You have an invoice with invoice pdf as attachment. If you don't have delete rights for the invoice (maybe only read rights), you're not allowed to delete the attachment of that invoice, too.

So the only solution to your problem is to override [that logic](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_attachment.py#L225).

Comment: The documents in the directories are documents created by the administrator, usually text files, like an operation manual. The documents don't belong to a special model, so I don't know what extra permissions I have to give to the group knowledge/user

Comment: Oh ok, than "forget" my answer :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want user to belong to Employee group, create user as a Portal User.
(Giving user access to standard apps automatically makes user belong to Employee group as most of them inherit Employee group) 
Now, you have 2 options : 
1) Modify Portal group to include Knowledge menu & related objects access 
2) Create new group inheriting Portal group with required menu & related objects access. 
Assign new user with this group access to allow accessing Documents.